# What does a tornado on the map mean?

Tags: pokemon-go

There is a tornado like swirl on my map. It has dust clouds lighting coming from it. It is in a random spot next to a poke stop. Nothing is popping up in that circle. It is not attached to me like it looks like in the picture. My brother has Pokémon Go and it is not showing up on his.  What does this tornado indicate?

[image: tonado screenshot]

Comment: Looks kinda like the animation gyms use to indicate they are under attack... Game client on your device might have glitched for some random reason.

Comment: Are you or your brother under 13, by any chance?

Comment: @Joe I don't see how age is relevant to glitches that occur

Comment: New Wind type pokemon confirmed?

Comment: @Wondercricket Players of age < 13 are unable to see sponsored pokestops and gyms.  It's possible that there is a sponsored gym there with a battle ongoing (and there's a sometimes glitch that causes this to show up for some people/in some situations and not others).

Comment: Definitely a mostly invisible gym, you can even see one of the floating spot lights.  Either the gym hasn't fully rendered yet, or as others have said it can't be seen due to age restriction.

Answer (score 12):

The tornado matches the exact animation of a [gym](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Gym_(Pok%C3%A9mon_GO)) under attack. It must have been a glitch in the game, but in my personal experience, I have never encountered this problem.

The game always has weird glitches, and if your brother did not see the tornado, it is more evidence that it is a glitch.